# Add multiple variables to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am loading files from multiple directories and collecting the paths in a dictionary.

```
directory_list = ["A", "B"]

for i in directory_list:
    path_1 = "U:/me/documents/{}/file1".format(i)
    path_2 = "U:/me/documents/{}/file2".format(i)
```

I want to collect these paths in a dictionary.

I could do:

```
directory_list = ["A", "B"]
dictionary = {"A": {}, "B": {}}
for i in directory_list:
    path_1 = "U:/me/documents/{}/file1".format(i)
    path_2 = "U:/me/documents/{}/file2".format(i)
    
    dictionary[i]["path_1"] = path_1
    dictionary[i]["path_2"] = path_2
```

but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way (I have more than 5 paths in total) than adding the paths one by one.

This is my preferred output:

```
{'A': {'path_1': 'U:/me/documents/A/file1',
  'path_2': 'U:/me/documents/A/file2'},
 'B': {'path_1': 'U:/me/documents/B/file1',
  'path_2': 'U:/me/documents/B/file2'}}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `directory_list = {k: {'path1': f'...{k}/file1', 'path2': f'...{k}/file2'} for k in ('A', 'B')}`…?

Comment: `dictionary[i].update({"path_1": path_1, "path_2": path_2})` perhaps?

Comment: How are you getting the paths ? Is it stored in multiple variables or you are getting it from some api ? What is the datatype for the paths ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
directory_list = ['A', 'B']
file_count = 2
file_numbers = range(1, file_count+1)

file_paths = {d:{f'path_{i}':f'U:/me/documents/{d}/file{i}' for i in file_numbers}
              for d in directory_list}
```

Result:

```
{'A': {'path_1': 'U:/me/documents/A/file1',
  'path_2': 'U:/me/documents/A/file2'},
 'B': {'path_1': 'U:/me/documents/B/file1',
  'path_2': 'U:/me/documents/B/file2'}}
```